# jQuery/CSS navigation glitch on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, responsive-design, nav

I've got a navigation that slides out from the right-hand side of my website when you click on the menu button. I'm having an issue with the transition on the navigation not working on iPhone. **Here's how I have it set up:**

**The HTML:**

```
<nav id="main_nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="services"><a href="#services" class="anchor-animate"><span>services</span></a></li>
        <li class="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio" class="anchor-animate"><span>portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#contact" class="anchor-animate"><span>contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="social_wrapper">
        <ul class="social">
            <li class="linkedin"><a href="http://linkedin.com/in/jaredtomeck" target="_blank">Let's Connect on Linkedin</a></li>
            <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/jaredtomeck" target="_blank">Follow me on Twitter</a></li>
            <li class="dribbble"><a href="http://dribbble.com/jaredtomeck" target="_blank">View my shots on Dribbble</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- start #wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- start Header -->
<header id="main_header">
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#home" class="anchor-animate">jtwebfolio</a></h1>
    <a href="#main_nav" class="menu-link"></a>
        <a href="#" class="close-menu"></a>
</header>
    <!-- end Header -->
</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

**The jQuery:**

```
// Add class that determines whether navigation hides or shows when menu-link is clicked
$('.menu-link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
if($('#main_nav').hasClass('open')){
    $('#main_nav').removeClass('open');
}else{
    $('#main_nav').addClass('open');
}
});
```

**The CSS:**

```
#main_nav {
    background: #3B3B3B;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 7px;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease;
    transition: width 0.4s ease;
}

#main_nav .nav {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav .nav li {
    height: 33.333333333%;
    padding: 0 7px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#main_nav .nav li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Panefresco400wtRegular", sans-serif, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    font-size: .875em;
    height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 90%;
}

#main_nav .nav li a span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav .nav li.services {
    background: #ff8772;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ba5f4f;
}

#main_nav .nav li.services a {
      background: url(../img/navicon_services.svg) no-repeat center 41%;
}

#main_nav .nav li.portfolio {
    background: #009491;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #005a58;
}

#main_nav .nav li.portfolio a {
    background: url(../img/navicon_portfolio.svg) no-repeat center 40%;
}

#main_nav .nav li.contact {
    background: #ffc845;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #a7832c;
}

#main_nav .nav li.contact a {
    background: url(../img/navicon_contact.svg) no-repeat center 43%;
}

#main_nav.open {
    width: 50%;
}

#main_nav.open + #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav.open + #wrapper #main_header {
    width: 70%;
}
```

So basically, what happens is when you click the menu button, jQuery adds a class to the menu called "open," and removes the class if the menu's already been clicked. The CSS set's the styles that will show the navigation when you click it, but also contains the css3 transitions.

The stupid transition isn't working on iPhone. It worked on a friend's Nexus 7, though. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of why the menu's transition doesn't work on iPhone? I have tried a ton of stuff to get it to work, but it'd be nice to have fresh eyes on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really look into using a preexisting framework like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) for this, where problems such as this have already been addressed. This is only one of many issues you will face if you go down the DIY road...

Comment: How about a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could play around with the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` function instead?

Here's an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BP4we/49/). It has it's downsides, but it seem to be working on the iPhone.

CSS

```
#main_nav {
    background: #3B3B3B;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(193px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(193px, 0, 0);
}

#main_nav.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This fixed the transition issue. Now I've got to fix some other things to make it display the way I want it to. Thank you! I was absolutely going insane over this!

http://jtwebfolio.com/mobi <-- see it in action